# What is the default remote branch for git pull?

Tags: git

If I am on a branch and do git pull what is the default remote branch that gets fetched/merged?  What are the configurations that impact this?

Apologies if this question were already answered: when I browsed it was not clear which one directly answered this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There isn't one. You have to set one up.

You can Look at which branches fetch from which remote branches with

```
$ git branch -vv
```

You can change which branch your branch pushes/pulls from with

```
$ git branch --set-upstream <remote/branch>
```