# Configure "git pull" for default remote as origin branch of same name (without --set-upstream)

Tags: git

This is an obvious question: when doing

```
git pull
```

There would be an implicit expectation that the *origin* branch of the same name would be the source of the pull.  Now I had discovered several years back that were not the case. *But a mechanism for configuring git to have this behavior was discovered* and I have been taking advantage of that for several years.  Thus doing an explicit

```
git pull origin _mybranch_
```

or

```
git branch --set-upstream _mybranch_
```

has not been necessary.  Well .. until maybe the last couple of weeks.  I'm not sure what has changed in my environment (same laptop, same repositories..) .. but that shortcut is not working now.   So might there be some hint(s) out there about what I might have "lost" in my *git* configuration - I think at a global level - that would have disabled that shortcut?

The equivalent for *push* is

```
git config --global push.default current
```

But that does not exist for *pull* . Note that very similar questions like  [What is the default remote branch for git pull?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25752505/what-is-the-default-remote-branch-for-git-pull) do not mention this global git configuration/convenience.

**Update** A couple of *very* knowledgeable *git* folks are onboard. One o the comments was to clarify how the branch was created. Here we go

```
git fetch --all
git checkout existingRemoteBranchName
# make some local changes
git commit -m "Changed x,y,z"
# assume changes also happened on origin/existingRemoteBranchName
git pull   # Will possibly result in Merge Conflicts that I'll resolve manually
```

Comment: I think you need to update the config file of the .git folder.

[core]
 repositoryformatversion = 0
 filemode = false
 bare = false
 logallrefupdates = true
 symlinks = false
 ignorecase = true
[remote "origin"]
 url = https://github.com/xxx/
 fetch = +refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/*
[branch "rau-rel"]
 remote = origin
 merge = refs/heads/rau-rel

Comment: @RaushanKumar That's hard to read can you make it an answer?

Comment: Never mind what you think Git should do. Tell us, please, what _you_ did. Did you ever set the upstream for this branch? What does `git branch -vv` tell you?

Comment: I'm unclear what's happened here - you talk about previously finding a "mechanism for configuring git" for this case, but don't seem to actually say what that was. Is the question about a setting you made no longer working after a version upgrade? Or are you just saying you're sure there is an answer because you used to know it and have forgotten?

Comment: @matt  The point is that I did not explicitly do a `--set-upstream` and was thinking that had not been necessary.  I am thinking that my memory did not serve me well and instead was only for `git push`  which works fine without mentioning the upstream explicitly.    As far as "never mind what you think git should do" - i mean that's not the way we learn systems.  We try to understand how a system might/should work not _only_ how it _does_ work.

Comment: @IMSoP  I think I were misremembering and the "mechanism" only applies to `git push` (which does not need an explicitly set _upstream_) and not for `git pull`.  It is not clear why the latter should lack that convenience that the `push` has.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## TL;DR

My *guess* is that you're referring to `branch.autoSetupMerge` (and perhaps also `branch.autoSetupRebase`).  There is a lot to know about these, though.

## Long

There is a great deal of history here, along with some historical mistakes that are necessarily preserved for all time in case people depend on them.<sup>1</sup>  For the most part, though, these are the central concepts:

- A Git repository can have any number of *remotes*.  A *remote* is just a short name.  There's a standard—a social standard at this point, enforced only by defaults in Git—that your *first* remote is named `origin`.

  This short name stores a URL, and acts as the prefix for *remote-tracking names*.  If you only have one remote, it's wise to name it `origin`.<sup>2</sup>  That's simply because `git fetch` has a fallback: if all else fails, try the hard-coded string `origin`.
- A *branch name* like `main` or `master` can have *no upstream*, or *one upstream*.  The upstream setting is the one you have mentioned here, that you can set with `git branch --set-upstream-to`.  (The `--set-upstream` option was one of the mistakes, which is why `--set-upstream-to` exists here; the `--set-upstream` option is being phased out.  This is only the case for the `git branch` command: other commands that set an upstream still take `--set-upstream` or, usually, `-u` for short.)
- Commands that *create new branch names*—there are multiple such commands—can be told whether and when to set an upstream for the new branch.

I suspect this last item is what you refer to, rather elliptically,<sup>3</sup> here:

> *a mechanism for configuring git to have this behavior was discovered*

More to the point, I really have to *guess* here.  The tricky bits here are the behavior of `git pull` when given no additional arguments, and all of the various configuration knobs, all of which can interact.  So, let's look at the configuration knobs themselves.  These are items you can set with `git config`—which sets something for *this repository* only, and therefore must be run within a specific repository—or `git config --global`, which sets something in your own personal settings to affect *all* repositories, and therefore can be run outside of some repository.

(Note that if some setting is set both globally *and* locally-within-a-repository, the local setting usually overrides.  There are exceptions to this rule: for instance, `remote.remote.fetch` is a *cumulative setting*, so that local settings just add on to any global or system settings, rather than overriding them.)

With this in mind, there are two settings that you would normally set with `git config --global`:

- `branch.autoSetupMerge`, and
- `branch.autoSetupRebase`

These two control the next several settings *at branch creation time*.  That is, commands that create a new branch will set—or not set—the following items:

- `branch.name.remote` (contains the remote name, such as `origin`)
- `branch.name.merge` (contains a branch name: more on this later)
- `branch.name.rebase` (see below)

When you run `git pull` with no additional arguments, it is these three settings that control what happens.  Remember that `git pull` is short for *first, run `git fetch`; then, if that works, run a second Git command*.  The second Git command is usually `git merge` or `git rebase`.

For concreteness, let's say that we are on branch `xyzzy` right now, and we run `git pull` with no arguments.  This will run `git fetch` first.  The *remote* setting, stored in `branch.xyzzy.remote`, controls *which remote* Git will use with this `git fetch`.  If it's not set, the fallback is `origin` (modulo footnote 2).

Assuming this `git fetch` succeeds, `git pull` will go on to run its *second* command.  If `branch.xyzzy.rebase` is set to `true`,<sup>4</sup> the second command will be `git rebase`.  If false, it will be `git merge`.<sup>5</sup>  If set to specific strings as described in [the `git config` documentation](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-config), it generally means *use rebase, but with extra options*.

Both rebase and merge need more than `git fetch` needs, though.  In particular, both need a *commit*.  They do not need a branch name, though you can use one here and most people do.  They need a commit hash ID.  If you give them a branch name, they use `git rev-parse`—internally anyway—to turn it *into* a hash ID.<sup>6</sup>  The `pull` command, however, runs this second command with a raw hash ID.  The interesting issue is this: *where does it get this hash ID?*  We must now return to the `git fetch` command.

What `git fetch` does, in a nutshell, is have your Git call up some other Git.  Your Git is operating on *your* repository.  *Their* Git—whoever they are: this part comes from the *remote*—is operating on *their* repository.  **Each repository has its own branch names.**  Their branch names are *theirs*, to do with as they will.  Your branch names are *yours*, to do with as *you* will.  The names *do not have to match*, although for your own personal sanity, you probably will want them to match as often as possible.<sup>7</sup>

Anyway, for these reasons, when `git fetch` calls up the other Git, and the other Git lists out its *branch* names, *your* Git *transforms* these *branch* names.  They become your *remote-tracking names*.  Their `main` or `master` becomes your `origin/main` or `origin/master`, for instance.  Your `git fetch` will obtain, from them, any commits *they* have that you lack, that you need to update your remote-tracking names.  Then, at the end of the `git fetch`, your Git will update your remote-tracking names.<sup>8</sup>

The *commit hash IDs*, for these new commits—and all the old ones—in your repository and in their repository are *the same*.  Commit hash IDs are universal.  That's why Git uses them.  The *branch names* are not, which is why your Git stores their branch names as your remote-tracking names.  But the `branch.name.merge` setting here *predates the invention of remote-tracking names*, so what goes in it is *their branch name*.

When `git fetch` finishes successfully, it write a file—`.git/FETCH_HEAD`—in which it records their *branch* names and the hash IDs.  And then `git pull`, having run `git fetch` successfully, fishes these out of the file—or, in modern Git, where `git pull` is now a C program, takes them from the same in-memory data structures that Git used to *write* the file—to get the right hash IDs to pass to the second Git command.

So, if it's not too late to say "long story short", the `branch.name.merge` setting contains the *branch name as seen in their Git repository*.  When `git fetch`—the first part of `git pull`—runs, it sees that name; their Git says that *that* name means *some particular commit hash ID*.  Your Git make sure that you *have* this hash ID, obtaining any required new-to-you commits, and then uses the *second* Git command with that hash ID.

---

<sup>1</sup>This is a slight exaggeration, but only slight.

<sup>2</sup>Git is growing a mechanism by which you can choose a different default first name; once you've set this, with `git config --global`, it would become wise to choose whatever default you have set.  The details will depend on the ultimate implementation, but it's likely that `git fetch` will use this configured name as its fallback.

<sup>3</sup>I feel some irony here in accusing others of "using or involving ellipsis, especially so as to be difficult to understand".  See definition 1 [here](https://www.lexico.com/en/definition/elliptical), from the OED.  On the other hand, I like to think of myself more as fluent, loquacious, or at worst somewhat prolix.  But like beauty to the eye, verbosity is in the ear of the reader, so to speak.

<sup>4</sup>A boolean (true/false) setting in Git can also be made to "act true" by setting it to `1`, or "act false" by setting it to zero `0`.  The rebase setting can be any of `true`, `false`, `1`, or `0` to make it "act boolean", but it can also be set to particular alphabetic strings.

In general, Git configuration items that *can* be set true or false—even if they can also be set to strings—will have a *default* setting that is either true or false.  However, Git's configuration mechanism is so general that other defaults are possible.  You must therefore consult the documentation to be sure.

<sup>5</sup>In the special case that you are on an *unborn branch*, the *second* command from `git pull` is neither merge nor rebase, but rather a specialized variety of `git checkout` that creates the branch.  There were, in the past, some very bad bugs here: I got burnt badly enough 15+ years ago that I still mostly don't *use* `git pull`.

Even with the bugs long fixed, having seen how `git pull` confused me, and continues to confuse others new to Git, I personally still recommend using `git fetch` directly, followed by whatever second command you prefer.  This also gives you the opportunity to *look at what `git fetch` did* **before** you choose the second command.  Sometimes it matters.

<sup>6</sup>Note, though, that `git merge` also *saves* the branch *name* you give it to make up the default *merge log message*, if it winds up doing a true merge.  The `git pull` command gives `git merge` a raw hash ID, and therefore *has to* (and does) run `git merge` with the `-m` option to set a merge message; it includes the remote name and/or URL here.  If you split up your `git pull` into separate `git fetch` and later `git merge` operations, you won't get this default.  I don't believe that this default has much *value*, but do be aware of this.

<sup>7</sup>When dealing with *more than one remote*, this may be impossible.  Suppose, for instance, we have remotes named `fred` and `barney`.  Both of these Git repositories have a `wife` branch.  Fred's wife is of course Wilma; Barney's is Betty.  You can't have, in your own repository, one branch named `wife` to refer to *both* Betty *and* Wilma—and if you're married, using `wife` to refer to *either* of these two cartoon women is perhaps unwise.   So, you might have `wilma` as your local branch to work with `fred/wife`, for instance.

(This phraseology may be antediluvian, but so are Fred and Barney.)

<sup>8</sup>In very old versions of Git—predating 1.8.4—some `git fetch` operations fail to update remote-tracking names even though they could.  This is yet another reason to run a separate `git fetch`, although hardly anyone uses such an ancient Git version.

---

#### The `branch.autoSetup*` settings

Keeping all of the above in mind, let's look at *how we create new branches*.

Suppose that you have one remote, `origin`.  Suppose further that this one remote Git repository, over at `origin`, has branches named `main`, `develop`, `feature/short`, `feature/tall`, and `xyzzy`.

When you *clone* this repository, you get:

- a new empty repository that, before you get hold of it, has *all their commits* but **no branches at all**, but then
- as the last part of `git clone`, your Git *creates* one branch in this new repository of yours.

The branch your `git clone` creates is the one you tell it to, with your `-b` flag, at `git clone` time.  If you don't provide a `-b` flag, your Git asks *their* Git for a recommendation: *which branch should I create?*  They recommend whichever branch their `HEAD` says.  (If you're running a GitHub or similar repository for others to clone, there's a web page and/or API to set this so that you can provide the right recommendation.)  Let's say they recommend `main`.

Regardless of your configuration settings, this new `main` branch—created by `git clone`—has its `branch.main.remote` set to `origin`, its `branch.name.merge` set to `main`, and its `branch.name.rebase` not configured (so that it defaults to `false`).

Now that your repository exists, though, you can enter it:

```
cd newrepo
```

and create new branches.  One of the commands that creates a new branch is `git checkout` (or `git switch`):

```
git checkout develop
```

This seems to be a request to check out the *existing* branch named `develop`.  But *there is no existing branch named `develop`*.  Here, what happens is a bit complicated—and hits a bug in Git versions predating 2.23—but *usually* what happens is that we invoke what Git calls the *Do What I Mean* code in `git checkout` (or `git switch`).

This code checks to see if we have a *remote-tracking branch* that looks enough like `develop` to act as a *source* for a *new* (local) branch name `develop`.  And, since we have exactly one such name—`origin/develop`, which our `git clone` made when it renamed all their branch names—we do!

This invokes (internally, as it's all been coded in C for a long time now) `git branch` to *create* the name `develop`.  This `git branch` command can be told *set `origin/develop` as the upstream* or *do not set an upstream*.

The upstream setting of the new branch `develop` is composed of two of those three settings we've been talking about: `branch.develop.remote` and `branch.develop.merge`.  The *remote* part is to be set to `origin`, because that's the remote under which we find the remote-tracking names.  The `merge` part is to be set to `refs/heads/develop`, because that's the *full* name of the *branch* as seen in the other Git over at `origin`.

The argument to `git branch` to tell it whether to set this upstream is spelled `--track`: this is a historical artifact, from before the days of remote-tracking names and formalized upstream settings.  If `branch.autoSetupMerge` is `true`—which is the default—then this kind of DWIM branch-creation operation uses `git branch --track`.

There are other settings you can set here besides `true` and `false`.  See [the `git config` documentation](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-config) for details.

If you like `git pull` and wish to use it, but have it run `git rebase` as its second command, you should consider setting the `branch.autoSetupRebase` setting as well.

*Note that these affect both DWIMmed branch creation operations and `git branch`.*  However, in order *to* affect `git branch`, you must *create the branch with a remote-tracking name as the starting point*.  The `git branch` command can be used to create a branch in two different ways:

```
git branch newbranch
```

means, in effect:

```
git branch newbranch HEAD
```

which resolves `HEAD` to a commit hash ID (see [the `git rev-parse` documentation](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-rev-parse)) and does not set an upstream.  But:

```
git branch newbranch origin/xyzzy
```

resolves `origin/xyzzy` to a commit hash ID.  Since this resolution goes through the remote-tracking name mechanisms, `git branch` will set an upstream for this branch: `newbranch` will have its upstream set to `origin/xyzzy`.

This all depends on `branch.autoSetupMerge`, but that setting *defaults to `true`*.  If you have changed it to `false`, you'll need explicit `--track` arguments, or separate `git branch --set-upstream-to` invocations.

Comment: Well that's about a 4X longer answer to any other SOF question I've written (over 1K).  I'm in the middle of the treatise presently.

Comment: @StephenBoesch: hence footnote 3. :-)

Answer (score 1):

This is speculation, but what may be happening is that you follow a different workflow for some branches without realising it:

- If you create a branch locally, add some commits, and then push to a remote server, no default upstream is set, unless you include "-u" in the push command.
- If you (or a colleague) create a branch elsewhere, so that it shows up as a remote branch when you "git fetch", then the first time you check it out, a default remote *is* set up.

More specifically, when you run "git switch foo" or "git checkout foo" and local branch "foo" doesn't exist yet but "origin/foo" does, git actually runs "git switch -b foo -t origin/foo".

Most of the time, branches you create locally only need to be pushed, and branches created remotely only need to be pulled, so you just don't notice the difference until you have one that goes "in both directions" as it were.

Comment: I think that I understand your distinction between the treatment of push vs pull.  I'm not clear on why that affects the present circumstances in which the branch was created by other team member and is being pulled - but apparently requires a `--set-upstream` or explicit  parameters `<repo> <branch-name>` to do so.

Comment: It all depends how _you_ created _your local branch_. That's what I say this is _speculation_ - I don't know what commands you ran, so I don't know what settings might have affected them.

Comment: I see. The local branch was created by 'git fetch --all; git checkout existingRemoteBranchName` .  I'll update the question.